# UninferredParameterTypeConstructor exception during build when generic parameters not specified explicitly

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code (using **RxKotlin 0.40.1**):

```
class Result<T, E>(val data: T? = null, val error: E? = null)

fun <T, E> wrapResult(errorInfoFactory: (Throwable) -> E): (Observable<T>) -> Observable<Result<T, E>> = { it.map { Result<T, E>(it) }.onErrorReturn { Result<T, E>(error = errorInfoFactory(it)) } }
```

Just FYI this is needed to easily transform `Observable` which may throw errors to an `Observable` which always returns `Result` object, so `onError` is never triggered.

And I want to use it like this:

```
fun dangerousOperation() = 0

fun getErrorMessage(t: Throwable) = "error occurred"

fun test() {
    val resultObservable = Observable.fromCallable(::dangerousOperation).compose(wrapResult(::getErrorMessage))
}
```

And **Android Studio 1.5.1** with **Kotlin plugin 1.0.0-release-IJ141-56** doesn't highlight any errors in this code. But when I try to build it, I get the error:

> //Error:(24, 9) org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException:
>   Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Error type encountered:
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.ErrorUtils$UninferredParameterTypeConstructor@68754e6
>   (ErrorTypeImpl). //Cause: Error type encountered:
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.ErrorUtils$UninferredParameterTypeConstructor@68754e6
>   (ErrorTypeImpl). //File being compiled and position: (24,9) in
>   /home/d/work/workspace/Hitch-hiking-Stats/app/src/main/java/ru/netimen/hitch_hikingstats/MemoryRepo.kt
>   //PsiElement: val resultObservable =
>   Observable.just(dangerousOperation()).compose(wrapResult(::getErrorMessage))
>   //The root cause was thrown at: JetTypeMapper.java:435 // at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:299)
>   //    at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genStatement(ExpressionCodegen.java:339)
>   //    at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generateBlock(ExpressionCodegen.java:1532)
>   //    at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generateBlock(ExpressionCodegen.java:1485)
>   //    at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CodegenStatementVisitor.visitBlockExpression(CodegenStatementVisitor.java:56)
>   //    at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CodegenStatementVisitor.visitBlockExpression(CodegenStatementVisitor.java:22)
>   //    at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBlockExpression.accept(KtBlockExpression.java:44)
>   //    at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:280)
>   //    at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genStatement(ExpressionCodegen.java:339)
>   //    at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:309)
>   //    at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.returnExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1873)
>   //    at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$FunctionDefault.doGenerateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:50)
>   //    at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$CodegenBased.generateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:72)
>   //    at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:364)
>   //    at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:203)
>   //    at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:138)

But when I change my `test` function to

```
fun test() {
    val resultObservable = Observable.fromCallable(::dangerousOperation).compose(wrapResult<Int, String>(::getErrorMessage))
}
```

everything compiles OK. But why I get that exception when I don't specify the generic parameters of `wrapResult` explicitly if the IDE doesn't highlight any errors?

Comment: Exception during compiling is most likely a bug, and bugs are better to be reported to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is compiler bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11144.
Main reason why this bug is appear: function `wrapResult` uses generic parameter `T` only in own return type.